# Why the existed files cannot access on UBUNTU 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, netcdf

I copied pr_bias_c.nc and pr_bias_r.nc netCDF files from pendrive to my ncl_data directory on Ubuntu 14.04. The copied files are existed according to `ls -l`:

```
 beata@beata-HP-Z420-Workstation:~/ncl_data$ ls -l
total 5220
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 376916 zář 19 08:05 climatological_mean_monthly_pr_1971-2000_sm.nc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 376916 zář 19 08:05 climatological_mean_monthly_pr_2021-2050_sm.nc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 376916 zář 19 08:05 climatological_mean_monthly_pr_2071-2100_sm.nc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 182514 zář 19 08:29 Fig4.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata   7853 zář 19 08:04 lambert.ncl
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 193911 zář 19 08:28 lcmask.000001.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata   1080 zář 15 12:24 plot_pr.ncl
-rw-r--r-- 1 beata beata 376248 zář 19 10:54  pr_bias_c.nc
-rw-r--r-- 1 beata beata 376224 zář 19 11:05  pr_bias_r.nc
-rw-r--r-- 1 beata beata   1339 zář 15 10:19 simple_plot_pr.ncl
-rw-r--r-- 1 beata beata   1092 zář 14 12:55 simple_plot_pr.ncl~
-rw------- 1 beata beata 376888 zář 19 09:22 UNEP_1971-2000.nc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 377252 zář 19 09:29 UNEP_1971-2000_sm.nc
-rw------- 1 beata beata 376888 zář 19 09:23 UNEP_2021-2050.nc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 377252 zář 19 09:35 UNEP_2021-2050_sm.nc
-rw------- 1 beata beata 376888 zář 19 09:24 UNEP_2071-2100.nc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 377252 zář 19 09:36 UNEP_2071-2100_sm.nc
-rw------- 1 beata beata 376948 zář 19 09:20 UNEP_E-OBS.nc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 beata beata 377304 zář 19 09:37 UNEP_E-OBS_sm.nc
```

When I type `ncdump -h pr_bias_c.nc` I get `ncdump: pr_bias_c.nc: No such file or directory`. The netcdf files are correct. I can use them in `Matlab` or in `PanoplyJ` softwares on `Windows`. I do not understand why they are not available on Ubuntu?

Comment: It looks like there is some additional (hidden?) character before the `p` in the `pr_bias...` filenames - you can see that they don't align with other files in that directory.

Comment: Thank you for your help! After I renamed these files they became available.